# Read operation on table 'sn_hr_integrations_todo_inbound' from scope 'Human Resources: Service Portal' was denied

Tags: widget, servicenow, portal

[image]

> Read operation on table 'sn_hr_integrations_todo_inbound' from scope
> 'Human Resources: Service Portal' was denied. The application 'Human
> Resources: Service Portal' must declare a cross scope access
> privilege. Please contact the application admin to update their access
> requests.

I've modified the OOB widget "HRM Todos Summary" and It is causing the below error.

I tried the following things:

1. Verified "Restricted Caller Access Privileges", no records are there related the error that i'm seeing. (Generally a requested or Invalidated record will create there, and when we allow it, it resolves the issues, but in my case its not happening)
2. I Created one "Restricted Caller Access Privileges" record but it didn't resolve the issue.
   [image]

Help is appricatiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:
Instead of "Human Resources: Integrations" scope I was trying on Global.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this script to bulk update from sys.scripts.do

```
function rca () {
  var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_restricted_caller_access');
  gr.addQuery('status', '!=', 2);
  gr.query();

  while(gr.next()) {
    gr.status = 2;
    gr.update();
  }
}

rca();
```